# vector::_M_range_check exception

Tags: c++, vector

I wanted to implement some sorting algorithms to compare them, and I stuck on weird exception.

Here's the code where Im sorting:

```
//InsertionSort.hpp
#ifndef SORT_INSERTIONSORT_HPP
#define SORT_INSERTIONSORT_HPP

#include <vector>

class InsertionSort
{
public:
    explicit InsertionSort(std::vector<int> v) : m_vector(std::move(v)){};
    ~InsertionSort() {};

    std::vector<int> save() const;
    void execute();

protected:
    void sort();

private:
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
};

#endif //SORT_INSERTIONSORT_HPP



//InsertionSort.cpp
#include <stddef.h>
#include "InsertionSort.hpp"

std::vector<int> InsertionSort::save() const
{
    return m_vector;
}

void InsertionSort::execute()
{
    sort();
}

void InsertionSort::sort()
{
    int x;
    size_t j;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < m_vector.size(); ++i)
    {
        x = m_vector[i];
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (m_vector[j - 1] > x))
        {
            m_vector[j] = m_vector[j - 1];
            --j;
        }
        m_vector[j] = x;
    }
}
```

And main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>


#include "Sorting/InsertionSort.hpp"

int main()
{
    /* random numbers generation  */
    std::mt19937_64 random(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 1000);

    std::vector<int> vec;
    for(auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        vec.push_back(distribution(random));
    }

    /* actual sorting */
    std::unique_ptr<InsertionSort> is(new InsertionSort(std::move(vec)));

    is->execute();

    auto result = is->save();
    for(const auto &it : result)
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout << result.at(it) << " "; //here exception appears
        } catch(std::out_of_range exc)
        {
            std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Exception is thrown, when I try to show sorted vector. When I debug this code line by line, vector contains 100 elements until the loop where I want to print out vector contents.

Comment: Not the problem but why are you using a unique pointer?

Comment: Yeah, thats the good question. I still have to learn how to distinguish when should I use pointer or to use smart pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`result.at(it)` is going to display the element of the vector at the index of `it`.  If `it` is `>=` to `size()` then `at()` will throw an exception.  To print out the contents of the vector you can just use

```
for(const auto &it : result)
{
    std::cout << it << " ";
}
```

This will output every element in the vector in the order they are in the vector.

As mentioned in my comment you do not need to use a `std::unique_ptr` at all in your code.  You can simply use

```
//...
InsertionSort is(std::move(vec));

is.execute();

auto result = is.save();
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating the vector incorrectly.

Two possible solutions:

1.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << result.at(i) << " "; //i - is an index
}
```

2.

```
for(const auto &value : result)
{
    std::cout << value << " ";
}
```